# Replace the variable value via symbol?

Tags: ruby

*var* is a variable that has some value stored in it. How to replace the value of *var* in *:var* (symbol) to *nil*?

Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. How is the variable `var` related to the symbol `:var`? Can you provide a code example to show what you’re trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If it's one or more local variables, call [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) on the implicit local [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Binding.html) using a String containing the assignment you want to make. Note that interpolation implicitly converts the Symbol to a String, so you don't need to explicitly call #to_s on the Symbol objects you're iterating over. For example:

```
local_vars = [:foo, :bar]
local_vars.map { eval "#{_1} = nil" }
```

If it's an instance or class variable, then you have access to Object and Class methods that don't require an explicit call to #eval. Instead, you can call  [Object#instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) or [Module#class_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set) on the instance or class object you want to modify rather than on the binding. For example:

```
obj = Object.new
instance_vars = [:@foo, :@bar]
instance_vars.map { obj.instance_variable_set _1, nil }
```